# Переменная доступная всем сайтам на сервере, PHP

Tags: php

Выделенный сервер Ubuntu 16.04.
На нем куча сайтов. Необходимо держать в памяти переменную, которая будет доступна на чтение и запись всем сайтам на сервере. Это можно как-то реализовать? Хранить в БД или в файле - не предлагать.

Comment: Чем БД и файл не угодили? БД - лучший вариант.

Comment: Я думаю, юноша имеет в виду кэш, но сказать не умеет. Насколько критична потеря этой переменной?

Comment: Что за переменная и зачем она нужна? Пока звучит как проблема XY

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.memcached.php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.memcache.php

Comment: Очень важно быстродействие. Переменная будет запрашиваться почти в каждом скрипте каждого сайта. Создавать отдельную "общую" БД для всех сайтов не хотелось бы. Если воспользоваться  memcache, то все сайты смогут видеть эту переменную?